# Adding a new empty column to sql select query

Tags: sql

i have the following sql select query

```
select column1,column2 from mytable
```

is a way to add an empty column to the query that doesnt exist in the table such as

```
select column1,column2,empty int column from mytable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this like that

```
select column1,column2,1 as column3 from mytable
```

Comment: but how do i specify the type?

Comment: for c# application, inside the property setter i want to do somthing like `_suppno = value ?? int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + supplierid);` , its more of adding the columns to the datatable rather than having to add them in code

Comment: If you need integer just remove quotes from my query. It will be: `select column1,column2,1 as column3 from mytable`

Comment: null is unknown type, use number if you want integer

Answer (score -1):

w3 Schools has a good section on this [SQL Alter Table Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp).

The specific command would 
    ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD column_name datatype

While it does not add the column in a select statement I believe this will accomplish what you are looking for.